# Understanding triangles on 2-sphere

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, spherical-coordinates

```
Suppose that you are two-dimensional being, living on the surface of a sphere 
of radius R. Consider an equilateral triangle with the vertices on three 
meridians, each 120 degrees apart and same distance r (r < πR/2) from the North 
pole.
```

I am trying to understand this statement but I am kind of confused. How can we form a triangle if the all the vertices have the same distance from the north pole ? Shouldnt they form circle rather then a triangle. I think if r wasnt constant then we could have form a triangle. Can someone help me to understand the picture of this triangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some $r$ you could choose:

- [51° 30' N 0° W](https://maps.google.de/maps?ll=51.5,0&z=11&t=m&q=51.5,0) (London, UK)
- [51° 30' N 120° E](https://maps.google.de/maps?ll=51.5,120&z=11&t=m&q=51.5,120) (somewhere next to the border between China and Russia)
- [51° 30' N 120° W](https://maps.google.de/maps?ll=51.5,-120&z=11&t=m&q=51.5,-120) (Dunn Peak Provincial Park, Canada)

and you get [this triangle](https://www.google.de/maps/dir/'51.5,0'/'51.5,-120'/'51.5,120'/@64,-3.0389257,1.99z/data=!4m12!4m11!1m2!2m1!2d51.5!1m3!2m2!1d-120!2d51.5!1m3!2m2!1d120!2d51.5).

**Edit:**

> Shouldnt they form circle rather then a triangle.

In spherical geometry the “lines” (in the sense of shortest paths) are the [great circles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_circle). But the 3 points do not lie on a common great circle for $r< \frac{\pi R}{2}$.

For $r = \frac{\pi R}{2}$ the vertices would lie on the equator and the spherical triangle would degenerate to a great circle.

Answer (score 2):

The sides of a spherical triangle lie along great circles. Except for the equator, no line of latitude is a great circle.

The midpoint of each side of the triangle will be closer to the north pole than any of the vertices are.